# How to handle 3rd Party assembly internally calling AutoMapper Initialize

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I make use of a 3rd party DLL which internally uses AutoMapper and initializes it with AutoMapper.Initialize() but then from what I understand, I cannot also call Initialize() as it clear existing maps.

What is the best solution for a 3rd party to use AutoMapper without conflicting with my own code?

Or another way.. how should a shared assembly set itself up with AutoMapper which guarantees it's own profiles are initializes but allows the consumer of that assembly to initialize it's own profiles?

Should the 3rd party assembly just define it's profiles and rely on the calling code to initialize all enabled profiles - manually adding profiles from the 3rd part assembly?

I am using AutoMapper 5.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is not to use the static instance of Mapper - create your own, and use Dependency Injection to inject an instance of IMapper wherever you need to use AutoMapper.  This also makes it a lot easier to test your code.

This is how I do things using autofac as my DI container:

```
builder.Register<IMapper>(c =>
{
    var profiles = c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>();
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });
    return config.CreateMapper();
}).SingleInstance();
```

This way, whenever I need to use automapper, I just add it to my constructor:

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

```
public MyClass(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    var mapped = _mapper.Map<Dto>(....);
}
```

}